# ObjectBox Always return null for inner data classes in Kotlin

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room, objectbox

I am using Retrofit for API Calls. 
I was able to cache data class which contains only strings and int.
But now I want to cache another model class which has nested model classes like 
below.

```
@Entity data class ConsumptionDashboardResponse(
        @Id(assignable = true)
        var id: Long? = null,
        @Transient
        @SerializedName("data")
        @NameInDb("data_consumption")
        var `data`: DataConsumption,
        @SerializedName("responseCode")
        val responseCode: Int,
        @SerializedName("responseDesc")
        val responseDesc: String,
        @SerializedName("sessionLang")
        val sessionLang: String )
```

**DataConsumption Class:**

```
@Entity
data class DataConsumption(
        @Id(assignable = true)
        var id: Long? = null,

        @Backlink
        @Transient
        @SerializedName("listDivisions")
        var listDivisions: List<Divisions>
)
```

**And Divisions Class**

```
@Entity
data class Divisions(
        @Id(assignable = true)
        var id: Long? = null,
        @SerializedName("aggregateBalance")
        val aggregateBalance: String,
        @SerializedName("aggregateConsumption")
        val aggregateConsumption: String,
        @SerializedName("division")
        val division: String,
        @Backlink
        @Transient
        @SerializedName("listConsumption")
        var listConsumption: List<Consumption>,
        @SerializedName("unit")
        val unit: String
)
```

**Divison class contains list of Consumption**

```
@Entity
data class Consumption(
        @Id(assignable = true)
        var id: Long? = null,
        @SerializedName("aggregateConsumption")
        val aggregateConsumption: String,
        @SerializedName("billingPeriod")
        val billingPeriod: String
)
```

I am unable to find if I need any type of custom converters or what else I need to do.

If I try to read saved data from ObjectBox this is what I get:

```
ConsumptionDashboardResponse(id=4, data=null, responseCode=200, responseDesc=SUCCESS, sessionLang=AR)
```

Answer (score 1):

A **`Transient`** field is ***not*** persisted in the database. If you have to store properties of **non-primitive type** either use [relationships](https://docs.objectbox.io/relations) or create [type converters](https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/custom-types).